# urllib2.Request 404 exception

Tags: python, request, http-status-code-404

Okay so I'm having an issue with 404, if my request reaches a 404 it throws an exception error.. rather than return 0 & continue with list

Code is here http://pastebin.com/48tspcEc

Comment: `return "0"` isn't indented properly inside the `if`.

Comment: Your indentation is poor, and incorrect. This isn't valid Python code - the first line of `get_total` isn't indented at all. I highly suggest you properly indent your code with 4 spaces per indentation level.

Comment: What do you mean? Why did you have to change it? Please edit it with the correct indentation

Comment: Uploaded code to pastebin with correct idents.

Comment: It's best to post your code here instead of making us jump through extra hoops like going to pastebin.

Comment: Also, saying "it throws an exception error" is nearly useless.  What is the exact error message that you get, including the traceback that shows the line of code that caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you indented correctly since python does not acquire a two spaced or four spaced indentation.
You should better post the detail of exception error in your question to analyze your problem.